# ado.net using Fetching the records from the database

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, ado.net

I am Getting this error at the time of filling data into the dataset

```
try
{

    cnn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(temp, cnn);

    cmd.CommandTimeout = 999600000;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    dscmd.Fill(ds);
    dt = ds.Tables[0];

}
```

SQL query contains 80000 records.

> The session has been terminated because of excessive memory usage. Try
>   modifying your query to process fewer rows. A severe error occurred on
>   the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

Comment: And what do you not understand about the error message? It's quite clear :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a SQL azure protection mechanism (error 40553, specifically), and has nothing to do with the calling C# / .NET / ADO.NET. The only way to fix this is to make SQL azure happy, by *processing less data*, or at least doing it in a way that pleases SQL azure. Without visibility of your sql command (`temp`), there is nothing we can offer here.

See also [Dipping My Toes Into SQL Azure – Part 2 – Protection Mechanisms](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2011/06/15/dipping-my-toes-into-sql-azure-part-2-protection-mechanisms.aspx).

There is an [associated note on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394106.aspx) for this error:

> Reducing the number of ORDER BY and GROUP BY operations in your Transact-SQL code helps reduce the memory requirements of your query.